# Is there any way to hide table in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, toad

Is there any way to hide a table in toad editor. It will work for me too if I only  could hide from the schema browser.

Answer (score 3):

Sure; create a **filter** which will remove it from a list of available tables.

Comment: Yeah sure, but it will show up in other client users. I want to hide it from other client users.

Comment: I don't think you can (at least, I don't know how). If people connect as the owner, they can do whatewer they want with their objects, which includes seeing them. You should create a new user, grant privileges on your tables to it, create synonyms for some tables and "hide" others.